# Having a hard time with OOP php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a hard time understanding OOP, I do not know what's wrong with this code.

basically I just need to select all the os_id from the database. this is the solution i came up and

```
public function select_all_users($fields, $table){
    $query = mysql_query("select {$fields} FROM {$table}");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $result[] = $row['os_id'] ;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

and technically this is how I would display it

```
require_once 'global/db.php'; 
$db = new Database();
$results = $db->select_all_users("*", "os_inventory"); 
echo "<td>". $results . "</td>";
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated.  You should stop now and learn using mysqli or PDO

Comment: it's returning an array, you cannot echo an array, it has nothing to do with OOP here. Also I'm not sure that you can pass `*` as string in `SELECT *`. And you'd better not, select col by col

Comment: First off, you _have_ to stop using `mysql_*` functions, the entire extension is deprecated, and will be removed. Secondly, you have to show us how you connect to the DB. Also: using `global/` suggest you're relying on some global state of something... inside a class (with its own scope) that always work. Read the docs on php.net on classes, namespaces, scopes...

Comment: If you want to use OOP even in the Database layer i strongly recommend using a ORM .

You can write it from scratch or just an existing one like Doctrine.

Comment: What is not working right with you code ? What does your function return ? You're saying you have a problem with your code but you do not say what does not work as expected.

Comment: @Stephan ORM is known to be great for rapid prototyping, but in the end is also perceived as bloated and heavy. Personally I wouldn't recommend it for use in production environments.

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes it depends for what ur using it ... if its for huge volumes of data then indeed its not recommended

Comment: @Stephan That wasn't listed in your comment. I have noticed with some people that once they used ORM for small things, they started using it for systems with big amounts of data too. And in the end, it will be bloated; with smaller volumes of data you're just less likely to notice it. Though I like how easy ORM is, this one needs a big "handle with care" label I think.

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes ur right... there can be a middle ground : implement ur own ORM in this way you can make it to your specific needs like : performance and wasy to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `$results` is array and you use echo!.
Use foreach like:

```
require_once 'global/db.php'; 
$db = new Database();
$results = $db->select_all_users("*", "os_inventory"); 
foreach($results as $temp)
    echo "<td>". $temp[0] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know what's wrong with this code.

### Everything.

From driver used to function itself.

If you want a database function to select all the rsults of the query, make a function to return all the results. But DO NOT restrict it to most silly query you can imagine!

```
public function select_all($query, $params = array())
{
    $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $stm->execute($params);
    return $stm->fetchAll();
}
```

Note that this code is using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) and you wull need a constructor to set $this->pdo variable